# cannot replace specific characters in stream edit

Tags: sed, csv

sed is such a wonderful tool, but for some reason I cannot make it do what I need this time.
I'm working with huge datasets in csv.
Some files are delimited with ;(semi colon) and others with ,(comma)

This should work right?

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i'' -e '/s/;/,'
```

It did not. So I though, o, lets escape them.

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i'' -e '/s/\;/\,'
```

No Luck there either.

Even tried ' vs " in all scenarios.
How can I do this without writing a python script and process line by line. There are 500M lines, so really do not want to go the RBAR way.

Comment: Is there maybe an alternative method that does not involve sed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it appears that sed cannot do this, and does not support special chars at the start or solo.
The alternative is as follows.

```
cat source.txt | tr ';' ',' > newsource.txt
```

It is blitzing fast. no issues with speed.
When working with big data, you might just need some extra space. I good idea is to maybe split your file in 2gb section when working with big data.